# Microsoft Excel: Is it possible to auto set column width based on the contents size?

Tags: excel

I have a pre-defined Excel template which i would be filling it with data using .Net C# code.

I know the size of some columns but some of them i don't know, so when i export data into the excel, the presentation doesn't look good.

This xls sheet is sent to customer. 1000's of documents generated every day like this. It's a tiresome work to every time open a newly generated excel document and change the width of the column to autofit by double clicking the column.

Is it possible in Microsoft Excel to AutoFit the size some column and not for few other columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
range("a2:d2").Columns.AutoFit
```

You could also use something like

```
range("a2").CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
```

or

```
range("a:d, f:g").Columns.AutoFit
```

Comment: do you mean in Excel template i have to add range("a2:d2").Columns.AutoFit  to my column?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps this should be included in your c# procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the VBA for it is:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Value In Target.Columns
    Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit
Next Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

- Go to the Developer Tab (have to turn it on via File>Options>Customise Ribbon.
- Open Visual Basic
- Select Thisworkbook
- Copy the Above VBA Code
- Paste into the VBA Window
- Close the VBA Window and the VBA editor